# Approve many tokens with one transaction

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20-approve

I need the users to approve the ERC-721 token before the smart contract and transfer it to someone. the default "approve" function works fine. but I'm wondering how to approve many tokens at once with one transaction. e.g. I have 1000 editions of an NFT with the current approve function will have to make 1000 transaction which is not acceptable.

any suggestions?

```
struct ApproveRequest {
    address to;
    uint256 tokenId;
}

function approveMany(ApproveRequest[] memory tokens) external whenNotPaused {
    for (uint32 i=0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        ApproveRequest memory token = tokens[i];
        approve(token.to, token.tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, we have to use the setApprovalForAll function https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-setApprovalForAll-address-bool-

Comment: approveMany works but the ideal way is to use the setApprovalForAll function :)

Comment: @vajad57 I wouldn't say "the ideal" way but yeah, that's definitely the usual way.

Comment: If you are the author of the NFT as well as the contract that would make the transfer, then you could just add in the NFT's code a way to bypass the `isOwnerOrApproved()` check when the `msg.sender` is your other contract.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be simplified if you could make the following assumption:

If all of the tokens should be `approved` to the same address, don't supply a struct of `ApproveRequest` but rather an array of `uint256`s and the `to` as a second parameter. This will save a lot of memory.

New sample implementation:

```
function approveMany(uint256[] memory tokenIds, address to) external whenNotPaused {
    for (uint32 i=0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        approve(to, tokenIds[i]);
    }
}
```

---

**⚠️ Note:** You could also use `setApprovalForAll()` however, **be extremely careful!**
When looking at the [OpenZeppelin ERC721 implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L376), `setApprovalForAll` will set the `to` address as an `operator`. Operators control **all of your NFTs** for an unlimited amount of time, even if you add new NFTs **after** the approval.

This consumes a lot less gas but comes with the drawback, that you cannot blacklist NFTs anymore and as already said, does also approve all NFTs that a user aquires after the the approval (which could be exploited).

Comment: You can of course undo setApprovalForAll after you are finished with the operations you want.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is, as you said, using `setApprovalForAll` from the `ERC721` interface.